# "Commit prior transaction" when using Explain Plan in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-execution-plan, explain

While Using Explain Plan option in SQL Developer, getting below error (mentioned in 
screenshot).

[image]

There is no uncommitted transaction in the session.

I am getting this error even when first time opening SQL Developer.

SQL Developer Version[image]:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug (27371100) - try upgrading your version of SQL Developer to at least version 18.1.

It's related to working with the plan table.

Latest versions shouldn't be committing/rolling back transactions based on an Explain Plan request.